# I want to sort my posts in my wordpress theme with two categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme, and as a beginner, I am having difficulties. The website will be a products portfolio, but not e commerce. It has a main menu of categories, and another menu on the sidebar with categories. The posts will be sorted by two categories. First of all, by the main category in the header, and then, those posts will be sorted by the other categories in the sidebar. I have no idea how to do this. Tried a lot to think of something, but I can't come up with anything. I hope you can help me how to sort it out.

I had an idea to use TAGS as sidebar categories, but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

The wordpress backend has a menu making system where you can make menus based on pages/posts/categories. These menu items will take you to a page with a list of all the posts existing in those categories.

So:

1. make your categories
2. go to the menu maker
3. create the 1st menu and assign categories
4. create your 2nd menu and assign categories

Use `wp_nav_menu()` to pull the specific menu in. The docs that I linked give you a good overview of how to get the menu you want.

You will have to style these menus appropriately.

Good luck and happy coding! If you have any specific questions, feel free to ask and I can expand on it further.